# Is $\frac{(3n)!}{n!(n+1)!(n+2)!}$ integer for any integer $n \ge 3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, factorial

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3497985/573047) and its comments, I suspect that:

$$\frac{(3n)!}{n!(n+1)!(n+2)!}$$

is integer for any integer $n \ge 3$, because I have run [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FractionalPart%5B%283n%29%21%2F%28n%21%29%2F%28%28n%2B1%29%21%29%2F%28%28n%2B2%29%21%29%5D%2C+n+%3D+1+to+2500) at WolframAlpha.

I tried some binomial coefficient manipulation, like in the linked question, without success.

Any idea?

Comment: [Searching with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B(3n)!%7D%7Bn!(n%2B1)!(n%2B2)!%7D%24&p=1) returns some posts on AoPS on this topic: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1573703p9677208 https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1236440p6286381

Comment: Thank you @Martin Sleziak. It turned out that one possible answer is already in math.stackexchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1001012/573047).